# Python - Continue not working in for loop?

Tags: python, for-loop, proxy, python-requests

Im connecting to a website with python request and that works fine.

My problem is that i have a list of proxies that im using, and if one of the proxy ip's is returning a 404 error, i then need my for loop to go to top of the loop and continue until i get a response of 200.

When my loop hits a exception/400-503 error it dosent return to the top of the code, but instead just goes outsite the loop, and continue the code.

**A quick note:** The proxy array has 6 ip's and the loop dosent get tru them all.

What is wrong, im using below code, with continue?

```
for l in list:  
    for a in otherlist:
        for proxy in randomProxy:
            print 'Using Proxy: ', proxy
            try:
                r = requests.get(url, timeout=20, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    response = r
                    print 'Good Proxy: ', proxy
                    pass
                else:
                    print 'Bad Proxy: ', proxy
                    continue
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                # A serious problem happened, like an SSLError or InvalidURL
                print "Error: {}".format(e)
                continue
```

I really dont understand why this happens, maybe i'm mistaken how continue works?

Answer (score 1):

This may work

```
for proxy in randomProxy:
    print 'Using Proxy: ', proxy
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, timeout=20, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            response = r
            print 'Good Proxy: ', proxy
            break
        else:
            print('Bad Proxy:', proxy)
            print('Proxy is not working!')
            continue
    except:
         print('Bad Proxy:', proxy)
         print('Proxy is not working!')
```

Comment: Sorry @Amey i had wrong indentation on stackoverflow. The for loop works perfect, but if it hits an exception or http error, then i want it to continue with the next ip in the list. But it just won't, do you have any good ideas?